# Limit to the amount of resources a player can spend when handling a crisis

Tags: archipelago

In **Archipelago** is there any limit to the amount of resources a single player can spend to deal with an internal or external crisis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a strong opinion on the communities that no limit exist. In fact, at page 7 of the rulebook, the following passage supports this: "Obviously, the first players will tend to use up the resources present on the domestic market board (I) first. Then they will use up their own resources, if they so wish".